# Modern and Legacy Bundle For Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel-mix

I want to mix for my Modern and Legacy Bundle project with Laravel that supports both old and new browsers (eg nuxt and vue-cli which do it with the Modern command) How should I do this please help.

Reproduce:

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#modern-mode
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-modern/